# U20.04 - Keyboard config stays in UK after all correct reconfig to US

Tags: keyboard, 20.04, input-language, language-support

I do all the settings selct for US kbd and locale but after reboot it still is configged for a UK kbd so hash and tilde are wrong etc.
I did both the GUI and the CLI procedures and the GUI says it is I set to U.S. But it isn't.

Comment: TBH it's not very clear what you did. Can you please edit your question and let us know the output of these two terminal commands: 1. `cat /etc/default/keyboard` 2. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`

Comment: Thanks Gunnar- that was it - just ensure /etc/default/keyboard is correct. Actually my bad - I should have done that.